# Set animated html5 canvas as the background without interacting with other elements?

Tags: css, html, canvas, background

I got the canvas working, I'm having issues trying to position it.
Specifically I want to implement them to the same effect as:

```
html {
  background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

for static images. Basically no interaction with other elements, and positioned as low as possible with regards to the stacking context. Additionally, I'd like to have the canvas background as compartmentalized / as segmented as possible from the rest of the code.

By segmented, I mean something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="backgroundContainer">
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="everythingElseContainer">
        ....
    </div>
    <script src="canvasAnimation.js"></script>
</body>
```

or this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <div id="everythingElse">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="canvasAnimation.js"></script>
</body>
```

to minimize the possibility of css conflicts.

```js
var WIDTH;
var HEIGHT;
var canvas;
var con;
var g;
var pxs = new Array();
var rint = 60;

$(document).ready(function(){
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 $(canvas).attr('width', WIDTH).attr('height',HEIGHT);
 con = canvas.getContext('2d');
 for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  pxs[i] = new Circle();
  pxs[i].reset();
 }
 setInterval(draw,rint);
});

function draw() {
 con.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
 for(var i = 0; i < pxs.length; i++) {
  pxs[i].fade();
  pxs[i].move();
  pxs[i].draw();
 }
}

function Circle() {
 this.s = {ttl:8000, xmax:5, ymax:2, rmax:10, rt:1, xdef:960, ydef:540, xdrift:4, ydrift: 4, random:true, blink:true};

 this.reset = function() {
  this.x = (this.s.random ? WIDTH*Math.random() : this.s.xdef);
  this.y = (this.s.random ? HEIGHT*Math.random() : this.s.ydef);
  this.r = ((this.s.rmax-1)*Math.random()) + 1;
  this.dx = (Math.random()*this.s.xmax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
  this.dy = (Math.random()*this.s.ymax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
  this.hl = (this.s.ttl/rint)*(this.r/this.s.rmax);
  this.rt = Math.random()*this.hl;
  this.s.rt = Math.random()+1;
  this.stop = Math.random()*.2+.4;
  this.s.xdrift *= Math.random() * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
  this.s.ydrift *= Math.random() * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
 }

 this.fade = function() {
  this.rt += this.s.rt;
 }

 this.draw = function() {
  if(this.s.blink && (this.rt <= 0 || this.rt >= this.hl)) this.s.rt = this.s.rt*-1;
  else if(this.rt >= this.hl) this.reset();
  var newo = 1-(this.rt/this.hl);
  con.beginPath();
  con.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  con.closePath();
  var cr = this.r*newo;
  g = con.createRadialGradient(this.x,this.y,0,this.x,this.y,(cr <= 0 ? 1 : cr));
  g.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,'+newo+')');
  g.addColorStop(this.stop, 'rgba(77,101,181,'+(newo*.6)+')');
  g.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(77,101,181,0)');
  con.fillStyle = g;
  con.fill();
 }

 this.move = function() {
  this.x += (this.rt/this.hl)*this.dx;
  this.y += (this.rt/this.hl)*this.dy;
  if(this.x > WIDTH || this.x < 0) this.dx *= -1;
  if(this.y > HEIGHT || this.y < 0) this.dy *= -1;
 }

 this.getX = function() { return this.x; }
 this.getY = function() { return this.y; }
}
```

```css
html, body, div, button, canvas, .containr {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body, .containr{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
}
html, body {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;
}

button {
  transition: all 0.24s ease;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 4rem;
}
button {
 font-size: 5.6rem;
}

#pixie {
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  background: black;
}


.containr>div {
  background: blue;
}

.containr {
  overflow:hidden;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 9;
 font-size: 256%;
 white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}


.btnz {
  margin-left: 2.4%;
  margin-right: 2.4%;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .36);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.btnz:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Outline Out */
.hvr {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}
.hvr:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #e1e1e1 solid 5px;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
}
.hvr:hover:before, .hvr:focus:before, .hvr:active:before {
  top: -18px;
  right: -18px;
  bottom: -18px;
  left: -18px;
  border: #ffffff solid 8px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head datetime="2015-10-31">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="containr">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div>
   <h1>Main Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
   <button class="btnz hvr">
    Button Butt
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I got the canvas working" create a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you've tried,

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay it's pretty messy since I've been messing with it non-stop for the past 3 hours. Sorry~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move objects down in the visual order use the CSS styling `z-index` smaller numbers move the element down under other elements, higher numbers bring it up.See [MDN z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for more info.

To set the background of an element to a canvas use

```
element.style.background= "url(" + canvas.toDataURL() + ")";
```

To isolate of compartmentalize some code the easiest way is to wrap it in a anonymous function and call it. Everything inside it is isolated. Use 'use strict' directive to  ensure you do not accidentally create global scoped variables.

A normal anonymous function does nothing and can not be used.

```
function(){ console.log(42); };  // does nothing
```

But if you wrap it in `()` and then add the function call tokens to the end `(` `)` you can call it like any function.

```
(function(){ console.log(42); })(); // send the meaning of life, 
                                    // the universe, and everything 
                                    // to the console.
```

The function below wraps up `a` and nothing can get access to `a` outside the anonymous function.

```
(function(){
   var a = 1; 
})();
```

But you can easily forget to put var in front of a variable making the variable visible to the entire page.

```
(function(){
   var a = 1; 
   outThere = 2;   // Oh no this is has been placed in
                   // global scope because it is missing
                   // the var token.
})();
```

To stop this use the 'use strict' directive.

```
(function(){
   "use strict";   // this must be the very first line of the function
   var a = 1;   
   outThere = 2;   // this will cause the javascript to throw a 
                   // ReferenceError: outThere is not defined
})();
```

It throws an error and stop the function from running but at least you will know that you have a leak.

Everything inside the anonymous function will manage itself. Deleting itself when not needed any more. Or remaining in memory if the Javascript engine holds an internal reference.

The next function starts up and calls its own function doSomething then exits and is deleted completely including the big array.

```
(function(){
    var bigArray = new Array(100000000);
    function doSomething(){
         console.log("Whats up?");
    }
    doSomething();
})();
```

The next one will create a big array and hold that array in memory for 10 seconds (lifeTime). This is because the `setTimeout` has given the javascript engine an internal reference to `doSomething`. As long as that reference exists the `bigArray` will remain (because of closure).  After the timeout the reference his no longer need and thus disposed causing all associated referances to go as well and thus disappear. All done via the magic of garbage collection.
Info on [Clouser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Closure)
Info on Garbage collection MDN is out of date but I am sure a quick search on StackOverflow will help.

```
(function(){
    var bigArray = new Array(100000000);
    function doSomething(){
         console.log("Big Array has had its time.");
    }
    setTimeout(doSomething,10000);
})();
```

Attaching an object to items outside the anonymous function scope will expose data in that object to the global scope.

The next function adds a property to a DOM element. This is visible to the global scope and also means that the lifetime of the function will be as long as that element exists.

```
(function(){
    function Info(){
        ... create info ..
    }
    var element = document.getElementById("thisOutsideWorld");
    var importantPrivateInfo = new Info();
    element.keepThis = importantPrivateInfo;
})();
```

But this does not apply to primitive types as they are copied not referenced. These are `Numbers`, `Strings`, `Booleans` , `Undefined`, `Null`...

So to set the background to a canvas via a compartmentalized function see the following function

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    var myCanvas =  document.createElement("canvas"); 
    myCanvas .width = 1024;
    myCanvas .height =1024;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // toDo
    // draw the stuff you want.
    var el = document.getElementById("myElement");
    if(el !== null){
        el.style.background = "url("+canvas.toDataURL()+")";
    }
    // all done
})();  // once run it will delete the canvas and ctx and leave only the copied dataURL
```

You may think that this exposes the canvas. But it is safe as the canvas is converted to a string and strings are copied not referenced.

If you need to keep the canvas for some period then use a timer to create an internal reference to the anonymous function

The following function will create a canvas and update it every second for 100 seconds. After that it will be deleted and completely gone.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    var myCanvas =  document.createElement("canvas"); 
    myCanvas .width = 1024;
    myCanvas .height =1024;
    var lifeCounter = 0;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // toDo
    // draw the stuff you want.
    var el = document.getElementById("myElement");
    function update(){
        // draw stuff on the canvas
        if(el !== null){
            el.style.background = "url("+canvas.toDataURL()+")";
        }
        lifeCounter += 1;
        if(lifeCounter < 100){
            setTimeout(update,1000);
        }
     }
     update(); //start the updates
    // all done
})();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That certainly helped alot, thanks! I've got it working, though I didn't set it as background. I just used a negative z-index and fixed positioning. Do you think it would be better to implement canvas.toDataURL() and set the html background, or is what I've done okay?

Comment: If you are animating `toDataURL()` is a bit slow. So just using the` z-index` is the best way. Don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the tick  if you feel it help address you question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you shouldn't use negative z-index values btw? I remember someone saying something about it somewhere~

Comment: The standard says that the most negative values are drawn first. Negative values are ok. I have always used negative values to move stuff down and never had any problems.